# Replace a value of a parameter in a file from Bash Script

Tags: bash, unix

I have this pair in my configuration file:

```
TheParameter="TheValue"
```

I am trying to replace the TheValue from a bash script like, with no luck.

```
sed 's/TheParameter="(.*)"/TheParameter="NewValue"/' /etc/my.conf
```

Can anyone suggest the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this example:

```
kent$  echo 'TheParameter="TheValue"'|sed 's/\(TheParameter="\).*/\1newValue"/'
TheParameter="newValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed`, by default, uses basic REs, in which `()` are not special (don't capture or group). You either need to escape them (`\(.*\)`), use the `-E` flag (extended REs), or drop them entirely.